# Best practice of wrapping text around image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

This is how i want it to be placed. On the bottom-right.

I am using bootsrap 3 as a framework. I have seen sugestions like using a table to place it or floats, or margin. I think margin is pretty much out of the question, because you know, responsiveness. I was thinking about wrapping the text and image in a container and absolute position the image. Is that ok? If not what would be the best practice to handle this?

Comment: absolute positioning is out of the question. You need to use float: right;

Answer (score 0):

According to me best way is :

```
.image{
  position:relative;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0;
}
```

This way image will always stay in bottom right to the container on every device.

Using

```
Float:right
```

you won't be able to place it on bottom right it will be right only.

Using display as table-cell will place all of the content in bottom right not just image.
using Absolute is the worst way.

Hope this helps...